# In $V[[z]]$, why is it allowed to separate Taylor series to infinite sum of "smaller" sums?

Tags: abstract-algebra, power-series, formal-power-series

I'll give you an example in $\mathbb{C}[[x, y]]$:

$$\sum_{n,m\in \mathbb{N}} \binom{n+m}{m} x^ny^m =\sum_{k\in \mathbb{N}}\sum_{n+m=k} \binom{n+m}{m}x^ny^m =\sum_{k\in\mathbb{N}} (x+y)^k=\frac{1}{1-x-y}$$

Why are we allowed to write the first equality? How is that rigorously defined in our space? We have infinite sum of vectors in $\mathbb{C}[[x, y]]$.

Comment: $\Bbb{C}[[x,y]]$ is a **topological** vector space, the topology is somehow needed to write the first double series. And it is evident that in this topology this is equal to (converges to the same as) the second series.

Comment: Of note topological complex vector space often assumes that $\Bbb{C}$ is with the Euclidean topology, whereas on $\Bbb{C}[[x,y]]$ it is often natural to put the discrete topology on $\Bbb{C}$.

Comment: So this is not well-defined *unless* additional structure is imposed on vector space. Good to know since I've seen this used numerous times in vertex algebra and VOA theory (actually everywhere where formal calculus is used).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$R[[X]]$ is not just a vector space, it is a topological vector space. There are several ways you can introduce topology (as written [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_power_series#Topological_structure)), but the important thing is that it is the finest topology such that all sequences of partial sums $$S_n = a_0+a_1X+\ldots+a_nX^n$$ converge to the corresponding power series $\displaystyle\sum_{i=0}^\infty a_iX^i$.

This is precisely why we are able to write $$(1,0,0,\ldots)+(0,1,0,\ldots)+\ldots = (1,1,1,\ldots)$$ since we think of the LHS as a sequence of partial sums that converges to the RHS.